# HibernateException when creating subentity in listener

Tags: java, hibernate

Suppose we have some entities that look like this (I'll try to keep it simple):

```
@Entity
class MainEntity {
  //nothing too special here
}

@Entity
class DependentEntity implements Serializable {

  @Id    
  @OneToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false )
  @JoinColumn( name = "mainEntityId", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false )
  private MainEntity mainEntity;
}

@Entity
@IdClass(AnotherDependentEntityId.class)
class AnotherDependentEntity {

  @Id    
  @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false )
  @JoinColumn( name = "mainEntityId", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false )
  private MainEntity mainEntity;

  @Id
  @Column ( name = "type", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false )
  private SomeEnum type;
}
```

As you can see there can be at most one `DependentEntity` for each `MainEntity` but multiple `AnotherDependentEntity` - one for each value of `SomeEnum`.

Now whenever someone creates a `MainEntity` we want to create the necessary `DependentEntity` and `AnotherDependentEntity` instances as well. We're trying to do this via a `PostInsertEventListener` and a dependent sub-session, like this:

```
Session subSession = pEvent.getSession().sessionWithOptions()         
    .autoClose( true)        
    .autoJoinTransactions( true )        
    .noInterceptor()
    .openSession();

subSession.saveOrUpdate( new DependentEntity( mainEntity ) );
subSession.saveOrUpdate( new AnotherDependentEntity ( mainEntity, SomeEnum.VALUE1 ) );
```

It works well for `DependentEntity` but doesn't for `AnotherDependentEntity` and we can't figure out why.

We get the following message for the second `saveOrUpdate()`:

> HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.HibernateException: No part of a composite identifier may be null]
>   
> <sub>(in org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer$IncrediblySillyJpaMapsIdMappedIdentifierValueMarshaller.getIdentifier(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:367) )</sub>

When debugging the code it seems that when the persist on the `AnotherDependentEntity` is executed the `mainEntity` property is null even though it was set before (and the same debug location in the original session had it properly set as well).

This leads to the impression that `mainEntity` must somehow be set to null but even a value watching breakpoint didn't get triggered so it must occur via reflection (and we verified it was the same `AnotherDependentEntity` instance in both cases).

So here's the question:

Does anyone know why/where that part of the id is set to null? And maybe we're doing it all wrong and there's a better way to do it (note: we can't add references into `MainEntity` and just let it get cascaded for several reasons).

Environment: Wildfly 10.1.0 with Hibernate 5.2.7

**Edit:**

One more thing we observed: while debugging one can see that the entity persister has a reference to both the entity and an instance of the id-class (i.e. `AnotherDependentEntityId`). The id-class contains both values, i.e. both fields are null while the actual entity's id has been partially nulled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours of debugging the situation has become much clearer:

**Situation analysis**

Eventually `AbstractEntityTuplizer.setIdentifier(...)` will be called for the entity after which the reference `mainEntity` became null.

That method's body basically looks like this:

```
if ( entityMetamodel.getIdentifierProperty().isEmbedded() ) {
        if ( entity != id ) {
            //copy the id (snipped for simplicity)
        }
    }
    ... //check and handling for a setter, not relevant here
    else if ( identifierMapperType != null ) {
        mappedIdentifierValueMarshaller.setIdentifier( entity, id, getEntityMode(), session );
    }
```

In our case the `mappedIdentifierValueMarshaller` has been called and, as you probably guessed, it's an instance of `IncrediblySillyJpaMapsIdMappedIdentifierValueMarshaller`.

That marshaller gets both the entity (which has the reference `mainEntity` properly set) as well as an instance of the id-class which contains a field `Long mainEntity` (the id of the main entity is a `Long`) that is also properly set.

Now the marshaller, being named "incredibly silly", decides it needs to look up the id components via the values in the id-class and set the properties on the entity accordingly. However, since we're operating in a new session trying to find the referenced `MainEntity` in the persistence context fails (the persistence context is a new empty instance) and hence `mainEntity` is set to null via reflection.

**Suggested fix**

So far so good, we now know what happens. But how do we fix it?

Unfortunately there seems no easy way to "register" the `MainEntity` with the new session's persistence context and going the hard route (via casts etc.) doesn't see wise, there's probably no easy way for a reason.

However, since it works with `DependentEntity` there must be a difference. With that entity the tuplizer went straight into the first branch, i.e. the identifier seems to be mapped as "embedded" and both `entity` and `id` are the same instance thus `setIdentifier(...)` doesn't do anything.

As it turns out what makes the difference is the presence of the id-class. Removing it and making `AnotherDependentEntity` implement `Serializable` fixes the issue and as far as we can tell there are no side effects (if there are we'd be glad for someone to point them out).

The entity now looks like this:

```
@Entity
class AnotherDependentEntity implements Serializable {

  @Id    
  @ManyToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false )
  @JoinColumn( name = "mainEntityId", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false )
  private MainEntity mainEntity;

  @Id
  @Column ( name = "type", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false )
  private SomeEnum type;
}
```

One might ask "how do I use `EntityManager.find(...)` without an id-class?". Here's how it seems to work:

```
Long mainEntityId = ...;
SomeEnum type = ...;   

//We only have the main entity's id so we need a reference
MainEntity mainEntityRef = entityManager.getReference( MainEntity .class, mainEntityId );

//Create a "prototype" for the lookup, only the id values are relevant
AnotherDependentEntity lookupEntity = new AnotherDependentEntity( mainEntityRef, type);

//Now perform the actual find, i.e. find the entity which matches the id of the lookup entity
AnotherDependentEntity actualEntity = entityManager.find( AnotherDependentEntity.class, lookupEntity );
```

Comment: removing @IdClass  works with me, but this solution make our app dependent on Hibernate and we lost portability ,   did you find any other workaround ?   its very silly bug indeed

Comment: @SamyOmar unfortunately not and after finding that "workaround" we moved on. In our case depending on Hibernate isn't a problem since we know our deployment environment and use other Hibernate-specific functionality anyways. That being said, being able to switch JPA implementations often isn't an actual requirement so you might want to evaluate whether or not your really need that portability.

Answer (score 1):

I found an issue in [hibernate.atlassian](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6044). Try this solution to work...

Comment: Hmm, while it looks similar I'm not sure it's the same problem. Besides that, I didn't see a solution, but maybe I'm blind at that ;)

Comment: Ah, no it isn't null. I'll add that to my question.